# Terminals no longer work in Visual Studio Code after updating to macOS 14.1

Tags: macos, terminal, applications, software-update, sonoma

I recently updated my MacBook Pro to macOS 14.1. I opened a folder Visual Studio Code and tried to run the command `npm start`. The first time, Node.JS crashed, giving me an error message that basically means "Node could not get stdin (POSIX terminal input) when the running script tried to access it". I tried running `npm start` again, but then it just froze without telling me anything. I closed the terminal instance and opened a new one, but the new instance froze as well, with Visual Studio Code telling me that it couldn't connect to the terminal instance (this message showed as a widget in the status bar). When I clicked the widget, the whole application froze, and I had to force quit it. This issue has never occurred before until I updated macOS.

Comment: If you run Terminal.app directly (via Spotlight), does `npm` work?

Comment: @nohillside It did have a similar freeze at the beginning, but for some reason, both the macOS terminal and the Visual Studio Code terminal work fine now. I would of course still like to find out how this happened in the first place.